# Are slaver wasps constructs or specially bred?

Tags: girl-genius

Is it ever clarified how the wasps came to be in the comics or the novels (I've recently re-read from the beginning and I didn't see anything).  Are they a special sort of construct, or are they specially bred and manufactured, like the weasels?

I originally was going to ask if they were clanks, but I noticed that there is no sort of mechanism in them in all the appearances of wasps.  It also wouldn't account for how they evolve.

Comment: IMO everything which isn't completely natural, but isn't clank (mechanical) is construct - from slightly modified humans to completely artificial beings as wasps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that the wasps themselves were grown, from a construct, called the "Hive Engine".  I'm at work at the moment, but will add references later.

They aren't built directly ( Agatha -> Dingbot Prime ) but rather Other -> Hive Engine -> Slaver Wasps.  And the Hive Engine has obviously mechanical parts.

Comment: Doesn't the Hive Engine support some sort of 'queen', which in turn spits out the wasps? Maybe that's the construct?

Comment: @CBredlow - they'd both be constructs, which is kind of a catch-all word for any sort of artificial creature (but more commonly applied to the sentients).  But yeah, you're right.